# Allow `public` to listen to changes, but only to items to which they have the `id`. GraphQL Amplify API

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

This is my schema. how can I allow onUpdateOrderSubscription (ONLY if they filter by ID), but disallow `OnCreateOrderSubscription`. I am using the AWS Amplify GraphQL api

```
type Order @model 
  @auth(rules: [
      { allow: public, operations: [create, get, listen]},
    ]) {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  paymentProvider: String!
  paymentID: String
  paymentURL: String
  product: Product! @hasOne
}
```

My use case is that I have an order details page, that I want to be synced with the data on the graphql api. But I don't want users to be able to have any read access to orders to which they don't have the ID